# UIWebview enable cookies

Tags: ios, cookies, uiwebview

I am trying to access a specific URL that requires cookies through `UIWebView` but I can not access it because cookies are disabled. So I did the following:

- Enabled cookies:

  ```
  NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

  [cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
  ```
- Created `NSURLConnection` and extracted cookies from response:

  ```
  NSArray *cookies = [ NSHTTPCookie cookiesWithResponseHeaderFields: [ httpResponse allHeaderFields ] forURL:response.URL];

  [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookies: cookies forURL: response.URL mainDocumentURL:nil];
  ```

But neither of this didn't help. However if I launch the URL in safari it loads successfully and after that I can load the same URL in `UIWebView` too. Could you help me with this, how can I enable cookies for `UIWebView`?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

After create a `NSURLRequest`, copy all cookies in sharedHTTPCookieStorage to `NSURLRequest`:

```
NSArray *cookies = [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:YES];
[self addCookies:cookies forRequest:request];
[_webView loadRequest:request];
```

And add `addCookies:forRequest` method

```
- (void)addCookies:(NSArray *)cookies forRequest:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request
{
    if ([cookies count] > 0)
    {
        NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
        NSString *cookieHeader = nil;
        for (cookie in cookies)
        {
            if (!cookieHeader)
            {
                cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@=%@",[cookie name],[cookie value]];
            }
            else
            {
                cookieHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@; %@=%@",cookieHeader,[cookie name],[cookie value]];
            }
        }
        if (cookieHeader)
        {
            [request setValue:cookieHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Cookie"];
        }
    }
}
```